# git folder on centOS 6

Tags: git, centos

I installed red hat openshift tools on CentOS 6.3.
Then I checked

```
git --version
```

It is already installed, but I don't know whether it was installed before openshift tools or not. I configured git:

```
git config --global user.name "myname"
```

Then I wanted to check "visually" whether .gitconfig file is created somewhere in a file system.
However, I cannot find where it is. If I issue:

```
git config --list
```

it shows my configuration. So can someone explain me where .gitconfig file is and where git/bin directory is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git config --local` or `git config` is per repo config and is found in the repo itself in `.git/config`

`git config --global` is per user and can be found in `~/.gitconfig`

`git config --system` is per machine and the `.gitconfig` file can be found where git looks for it's supporting files.

Comment: since git v1.7.12, global config (XDG config) can also exist in ~/.config/git/config

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `mlocate` and do a `locate git`?

Comment: OP is asking for .gitconfig, not git

Answer (score 0):

It's in ~/.gitconfig here, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Nautilus to browse, but the folder/files were hidden. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> shows hidden folders and files.